# Adding compression variable to CopyRaster_management for TIFF Raster Dataset?

Tags: arcpy, raster, geotiff-tiff, compression

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

I need tiff orthos to have NO compression. I'm using a python script to parse through directories and add 4-band data to the images. It works great ... but the customer wants it uncompressed. The process creates them in LZW by default.

The copyraster info page states: out_rasterdataset --> "When storing a raster dataset to a JPEG file, JPEG 2000 file, TIFF file, or geodatabase, you can specify a compression type and compression quality."

**How do I set the compression type to None?**

I have tried arcpy.env.compression = "NONE" but this does NOT work. I even added the pyramid environment variable. No dice.

Here's what I'm using now and it works, but the compression is still LZW:

```
import os,arcpy,glob
```

rasterpath = r"source-directory"
outFolder = r"end-directory"

arcpy.env.workspace = rasterpath
arcpy.env.pyramid = "PYRAMIDS -1 BILNEAR NONE NO_SKIP"
arcpy.env.compression = "NONE"

for rasterFile in arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif"):
    oName, oExt = os.path.splitext(rasterFile)
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, oName+ ".tif")
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile,outRaster,"DEFAULTS","255","255","","","8_BIT_UNSIGNED")

In order to get no compression, I have to open each file and export data. If the no compression variable won't work in the current script, I'm fine with creating a new script. Basically, I want this screen in script form:

[image]

Comment: The documentation for [CopyRaster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) claims that it acknowledges the [Compression environment setting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/environments/compression.htm). If it's not working correctly, please submit it as a bug to ESRI.

Comment: LZW is lossless. Do you really need it to be None, or do you just need it to be lossless?

Comment: Customer is demanding no compression at all. I don't know why but they are.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using? Going back to 10.3, I'm not seeing TIFF included in that quote you gave about compression environments.

Comment: That said, my tests (in 10.5) are showing that CopyRaster to tif accepts my compression environment settings, both None and other.

Comment: Hi Tom. It appears to be v 10.1. Since that compression environment seems to be a fail, what about an export raster window replacement script. I know this compression type none works. I've just spend all morning loading up a tiff and manually exporting it.

Comment: You can't replace that window with a script...not without going all crazy with ArcObjects. Try using the [RasterToOtherFormat](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_To_Other_Format/001200000032000000/) tool instead.